# Search code datasheed

Tags: vb.net

i can't search by letters. Something like Jam. I have to write the full name like James. Can someone help me to change the code so i can search by letters.

This is my code

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim Load As SearchFromTable = New SearchFromTable

    With Me.DataGridView1
        .DataSource = Load.GetMyData _
        ("Select *" _
         + " From tblInfo Where Fname='" & Trim(Me.txtSearch.Text) & "'" _
         + " or Lname='" & Trim(Me.txtSearch.Text) & "'" _
         + " or Department='" & Trim(Me.txtSearch.Text) & "'" _
         + " or Company='" & Trim(Me.txtSearch.Text) & "'")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Add % after the text you want to search. Your code is wide open to sql injection by the way.

Comment: You should use `LIKE` rather than `=`

Answer (score 0):

Like Jaxi said, use LIKE:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim Load As SearchFromTable = New SearchFromTable

    With Me.DataGridView1
        .DataSource = Load.GetMyData _
        ("Select *" _
         + " From tblInfo Where Fname like '%" & Trim(Me.txtSearch.Text) & "%'" _
         + " or Lname like '%" & Trim(Me.txtSearch.Text) & "%'" _
         + " or Department like '%" & Trim(Me.txtSearch.Text) & "%'" _
         + " or Company like '%" & Trim(Me.txtSearch.Text) & "%'")
    End With

End Sub
```

The changes I made to you code will return anything in the string that contains "Jam", for example "James", "A Jam", "In a Jam", I Jam along with the band"  ... etc ....

Comment: You are my hero, Thx mate.

Comment: Maybe one more, when i loading my data from a Access sheet its insert all the columns. I don't want
insert the first one.
Is there an option to insert all the columns but "except the first column" or except the name of the column?

Comment: Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

        Dim Load As SearchFromTable = New SearchFromTable

        With Me.DataGridView1
            .DataSource = Load.GetMyData _
            ("Select * From tblInfo")
        End With

    End Sub

Comment: You will have to add each of the column names to the SQL statement that you want.  For example; `("Select Column2,Column3, Column4, Column5 From tblInfo")`  Just exclude the columns you don't want.

Comment: Then i have this fault: Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader() –

Comment: Is it possible to send u my project so you can take a look?

Comment: I use the 2017 version.

Comment: Prescott.Chartier@OrganizeMyLeague.com